# AWS EC2 certificate issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was deploying my Spring Boot app using AWS EC2 and S3 by running a jar file on a virtual machine. However, I'm facing a security issue when trying to fetch this url from the browser, which listens to port `8443`: `https://ec2-3-20-235-15.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/`

However, I'm getting [image: this error], which say `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. I've been trying to look into how to get SSL certificates for my EC2 instance, but have not found a way yet. I would really appreciate any help on how to properly set this up. I'm completely new to AWS...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your ssl certificate has a custom domain name, but you are trying to access your ec2 using the default ec2 URI which use amazonaws.com domain, so you need to create a cname record in your custom domain to point ec2 URI.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: You can use aws ACM to generate ssl certificate for your domain name, and aws Route53 to create a zone for your domain name the create the cname

Comment: By domain name you mean the one that makes request to amazonaws.com?